# Outlook 2007 Add-in form containing form with ActiveX control stuck in one off state

Tags: vb6, outlook, add-in

I have an add-in that contains a DLL and an OCX control, built in VB6.  Each is separate, meaning that the add-in consists of Addin.DLL and Addin.OCX.  The add-in uses a custom form, which is built off of the IPM.Appointment form in Outlook.  It is deployed to the user's machine as an OFT file and is published to their Presonal Forms Library in the initial OnConnection of the add-in.

I was having issues with the form being stuck in a one off state, which required me to add code similar the following to my AppointmentItem Write and PropertyChange class:

```
Private Sub AppointmentItem_PropertyChange(ByVal name As String)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Select Case name
        Case "MessageClass"
            Dim strGuid As String
            ' Check to see if this is one of our appointmentitems. 
            If IsItemUserItem(AppointmentItem_PropertyChange, strGuid) Then
                    ' Change to our add-in message class.  IPM.Appointment.XXX
                    AppointmentItem.MessageClass = gFormMsgClass
            End If
    End Select

done:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Trace "Error writing appointment item."
    Resume done

End Sub
```

This works for most cases.  However, I'm still running into instances where when I check the item during the NewInspector event if it is an Exception I cannot access UserProperties, which are used to facilitate data sharing between the DLL and OCX.

Additionally when trying to edit the form in the form designer, I cannot save the form as an OFT from Outlook 2007.  I'm kind of at a loss as to what is going on with this...Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it appears I have my own answer.  There were some user-defined properties added to the folder that were not added to the item and they were causing the one off issues.